# cURL works but XMLHttpRequest does not?

Tags: javascript, flask, xmlhttprequest

Making this call from terminal works:

```
curl -d "username=test&password=test" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/
```

But from my Chrome Extension, an Ajax call fails with status 0. I've tried a number of things but haven't had any luck.

```
function doLogin() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var params = 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password;

    sendPostRequest("http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/", params);
}

function sendPostRequest(url, params) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('POST', url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
        // This is never called
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            alert(http.status);
        }
    };

    http.send(params);
}
```

Server-side:

```
@app.route("/login/", methods=['POST'])
def login():
    username = request.form["username"]
    password = request.form["password"]

    auth = authenticate(username, password)

    return jsonify({'authentication': auth}), 200
```

I would appreciate feedback.

Comment: Whats the error that you encounter in your console?

Comment: XMLHtttpRequest returns status 0

Comment: Check your console, an error must be logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recreated the scenario. If you want to access the `login` route from outside of the `templates` folder, you need to allow `CORS`.

I have installed `flask-cors` and allowed all origins. You may change this to specific `login` route if necessary. Documentation of the package can be found [in this documentation link](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Folder structure:

```
├── app.py
├── extension.html
└── requirements.txt
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.7
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pkg-resources==0.0.0
six==1.12.0
Werkzeug==0.15.2
```

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

def authenticate(username, password):
    if username == "test" and password == "test":
        return True
    return False

@app.route("/login/", methods=['POST'])
def login():
    username = request.form["username"]
    password = request.form["password"]
    auth = authenticate(username, password)
    return jsonify({'authentication': auth}), 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

`extension.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Chrome Extension Login</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    Username: <input type="text" id="username" /> <br>
    Password: <input type="text" id="password" /> <br>
    <button id="login_button">Login</button>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function doLogin() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var params = 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password;
    sendPostRequest("http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/", params);
  }
  function sendPostRequest(url, params) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('POST', url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.status);
        console.log(this.responseText);
      }
    };
    http.send(params);
  }
  var login_button = document.getElementById("login_button");
  login_button.addEventListener("click", doLogin);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

CURL request:

[image: curl request example]

Successful login with correct credentials:

[image: successful login]

Error in login with wrong credentials:

[image: error in login]

Comment: Thank you! I was missing CORS